# Вызов метода контроллера из другого контроллера (или как защить фронт от прямого перехода по ссылке)

Tags: c#, vue.js, asp.net-mvc

Всем привет.
Есть проект на MVC в который пришлось добавить фронт на Vue.
В MVC происходит авторизация по IP.
Если IP нет в БД, то просто выкидывает на страничку с отказом в доступе.

Вопрос
Как защитить авторизацией от MVC фронт, который работает на VUE.
Я думаю при загрузке страницы на VUE в onMount обращаться в API контроллеру.
И в API контроллере производить те же действия что и в контроллере, который авторизует пользователя в MVC.

Но там достаточно много логики. Можно ли как-то дернуть из API контроллера метод контроллера MVC. Или можщет для моей задачи есть какое-то иное решение без таких костылей?

Comment: Vue обращается к серверу, сервер возвращает 403, после чего сделать редирект на "отказано в доступе", все просто должно быть. Что используете для запросов? Axios? Можете завернуть его в свою обертку, которая будет обрабатывать такие сценарии.

Comment: @aepot Добрый день. Спасибо. Да, на фронте для запросов используется Axios.
А, если я в контроллерах API поставлю атрибут, что методы могут дергать только авторизованные пользователи, то никаких больше проверок и не надо выходит. Надо будет только обработать на фронте отлонение запроса для неавторизованного пользователя.

Comment: @aepot почему-то не могу плюсик на Ваш комментарий поставить :( (наверное репутации маловато)

Comment: В этом нет необходимости. Если у вас появилось решение, можете оформить его ответом ниже, оно может пригодиться будущим посетителям.